# Can DeepDream produce a "dream" from 3 images?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, deepdream

By default using the [DeepDream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeepDream) technique, you can create a dreamlike image out of two different images.

Is it possible to easily enhance this technique to generate one image out of three?

Comment: Absolutely. The convolutional neural network behind DeepDream can be trained using how many input/sample images you wish. More patterns in the training set determine a more pareidolic output.

Comment: @Lovecraft please put this as an answer.